# How does this capacitive soil moisture sensor work?

Tags: sensor, humidity, sensing, capsense

I’m trying to figure out how the following soil moisture sensor works.

It’s obviously a capacitive sensor where the capacitance changes when the soil moisture varies.

However, as you can see, the sensor is ENCLOSED, so how does the capacitor get contact with the soil moisture to sense it?

[image]

Comment: I know this post is old, but I was hoping you could tell me more about the sensor you posted? The manufacturer and model number for example.

Comment: That appears to be a Sentek "EasyAG 30" soil moisture probe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be also TDR sensor (Time Domain Reflectometer) if it very pricy. But also capacitive moisture sensors have the cap on it. Would you  expect to bury the whole electronics into the soil? Of course not, the self capacitance is somehow deducted with the calibration.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitive sensors never needs to contact a soil. Value of capacitor depends from dielectric capacitivity between and around capacitors plates.